# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Mail' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error in the controller. I've already added a use Mail statement before the class declaration but still doesn't work.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Redirect,Response,DB,Config;
use Mail;
class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail()
    {
      $user = auth()->user();
      Mail::to($user)->send(new MailNotify($user));

      if (Mail::failures()) {
           return response()->Fail('error');
      }else{
           return response()->success('Successfully send in your mail');
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883894/mailsend-not-working-in-laravel-5

Comment: thanks. I 've already tried this but it still doesn't work, I get another error.

Comment: Would you please share the error?

Comment: error 'Class App\Http\Controllers\MailNotify not found'. I've tried to declare use App\MailNotify;, but I get Class App\MailNotify not found.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change this dependency:

```
use Mail;

// ...
```

to this one:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

// ...
```

Also, add this to properly import the other class:

```
use App\Mail\MailNotify;
```

Just then you'll be able to notify your user:

```
Mail::to($user)->send(new MailNotify($user));
```

Comment: Thanks! I've changed it, but I get another error 'Class App\Http\Controllers\MailNotify not found'. I've tried to declare use App\MailNotify;, but I get Class App\MailNotify not found.

Comment: That's because this other class is also being wrong imported. When you reference/use a class inside another one, you should reference it using its namespace. Locate where that class is (your IDE should help you with this task) in order to imported it properly.

Comment: this use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail; saved my day , thank you

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on PHP namespaces and importing classes from namespaces.